# Convert pixel to color

Tags: colors, hex, rgb

How can I convert the following pixel to a color? (16bpp, RGB565, LE)

0x00 0xf8

I tried converting the numbers to binary numbers, but I'm unsure how to convert them to a color.

Thank you!

Comment: Do some research, and look for: RGB565 to RGB888 Color Conversion.

Answer (score 0):

What language? If you aren't using a language, just open paint and use the select colour tool and read what the hex is.